# How to stop (Cron Daemon) sending multiple emails?

Tags: email, notifications, centos, cron

I'm a newbie in server administration (centos 7) and have a problem with email notifications from the cron. There is 1 cron job.

```
15 * * * * user cd /var/www/domain/public_html/cron && php -d error_reporting="E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE" cron.php
```

and I set MAILTO in order to be notified about errors. But cron daemon sends me multiple emails every hour or two (also with previous cron errors). Then I wanted to disable email notifications completely so set MAILTO="" but still receiving messages. Probably there is a problem with mail or cron log. 
Permission denied after trying to clear maillog.

```
sudo > /var/log/maillog
```

Any suggestion what to do in order to receive only one email for the cron job?

Comment: Are you cron jobs fireing more than once as well by any chance? Check for `/etc/anacrontab` as you may be running both & that maybe why you get duplicate emails. I can otherwise tell you how to suppress errors from individual cron jobs if you want

Comment: I haven't touched anacrontab so it shouldn't be the reason... The problem must be somewhere in logs or general cron settings because I'm receiving old errors for old cron jobs, not duplicate messages.

Comment: from how long ago are these old jobs, and what do the email headers say ? You need to give us some more details please